# Powershell not handling wildcards

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

The script is a simple, rename and move/copy script to rename to a guid using the `$Id = [GUID]::NewGuid()` and change the name. Everything works when I point it to a specific file but when I change it to the

```
$source = "C:\Users\username\Pictures\*.jpg"
```

the *.jpg doesn't want to read and gives the following error;

```
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'C:\Users\username\Pictures\*.jpg' does not exist.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
My Script is below:

```
$Id = [GUID]::NewGuid()
$source = "C:\Users\username\Pictures\*.jpg"
$newfilename = "C:\Users\username\Pictures\$Id.jpg"
Rename-Item $source -NewName $newfilename 
sleep -seconds (5)
copy-Item "C:\Users\username\Pictures\$Id.jpg"  "\\Server\folder\subfolder\$Id.jpg "
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there - you actually need to get a list of the files that match `*.jpg` first and then iterate over them.

The below should do what you're after:

```
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\username\Pictures\*.jpg"

foreach ($file in $sourceFiles) {
  $Id = [GUID]::NewGuid()
  $newfilename = "C:\Users\username\Pictures\$Id.jpg"
  Rename-Item $file.fullName -NewName $newfilename 
  sleep -seconds 5
  copy-Item "$newfilename" "\\Server\folder\subfolder\$Id.jpg"
}
```